# PHP passing array variable from function

Tags: php, arrays

I try to work on an global array from a function. Here is my code:

```
$myArray = array();
myfunc($myArray);
var_dump($myArray);

function myfunc($myArray){
    //perform some other tasks
    $myArray['name']='John';
}
```

But didn't work. The `var_dump` return empty array. How can I get the array being pass up to the global?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass is as a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) `&`

Try doing this:

```
function myFunc(&$myArray){
    //perform some other tasks
    $myArray['name']='John';
}
```

You could also return it as such:

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray = myfunc($myArray);
var_dump($myArray);

function myfunc($myArray){
    //perform some other tasks
    $myArray['name']='John';
    return $myArray;
}
```

Comment: Why not `return` instead?

Comment: Yeah, that is another way to do it.

Comment: You can learn about references [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: & is reference operator, with it you are not only passing the Copy of the array's values, but the reference to the array itself.

Answer (score 1):

brenjt answer is probably the best, however the OP asked how to access the global variable.
You could access the $myArray globally using the global keyword, but you wouldn't pass that array into the function.

```
$myArray = array();
myfunc($myArray);
var_dump($myArray);

function myfunc(){
    global $myArray; 

    //perform some other tasks
    $myArray['name']='John';
}
```

This would *NOT* be the best method for accessing the array.  You should use the example by brenjt, but I wanted to show that this is also possible.